# xslt: How to ignore apply-template elements for which there are no matches?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is my XSL stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:pp="passcodeProfile">

    <xsl:template match="/">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="elements"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element1">
       output1
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="element2">
       output2
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<elements>
    <element1>value1</element1>
    <element2>value2</element2>
    <element3>value3</element3>
    <element4>value4</element4>
</elements>
```

The current spreadsheet outputs the value of the non-matching elements (outputs element1 element2 value3 value 4). How to ignore elements that are not element1 and element2 (outputs element1 element2)?

Comment: In XSLT one doesn't have "spredsheet"s -- one works with *stylesheet* s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your stylesheet outputs the original text nodes as well. You can suppress them by matching them and doing nothing with them, e.g. add `<xsl:template match="text()"/>`